# how to parse scope fields which contains HTML markup

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a very simple example here of angularjs with scope field: **title**.

I want the title ,which is "Hello world" to be introduce in subscript manner like this: [image]

The problem is , that angularjs doesn't parse  in the right manner and treat them as text only. How can I solve this, I have tried using $compile service and it didn't work properly.
I need a solution which is javascript and **not with HTML directives** like ng-bind-html.
Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("mainCTRL",['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.title="Hello <sub>World</sub>";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
  {{title}}
  
</div>
```

Comment: You have to use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: If those are two different parts of the title, that have different meanings – then probably they should be contained in two different fields/variables to begin with.

Comment: please read all my post, I need javascript solution

Comment: so no solution to my problem. I can't use ng-bind-html because my real problem is with labels on canvas so I need a JS solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind-html`, which will allow you to insert HTML elements as they are written in the string. 
Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml for more info.

Comment: By default, AngularJS will not allow you to do that. It's how AngularJS works, it's how `{{...}}` works.

Comment: so no solution to my problem. I can't use ng-bind-html because my real problem is with labels on canvas so I need a JS solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx) will help in clear understanding how to Render HTML with ngBindHtml.

Comment: I need to parse the element from js side without any directives of HTML like ngbindHTML